# How can I mosaic list of osgeo.gdal.Datasets and add overlapping grid cells?

Tags: python, gdal, merge, grids-sum

I have a list of osgeo.gdal.Datasets that I created from a list of numpy arrays containing geo-referenced ice velocity values for a glacier. I would like to merge these all into a single mosaic and sum the values in any grid cells that overlap. Is there a straightforward way to do this in python using gdal?

Comment: You could try the QGIS raster calculator if you only need to do this once or use GDALBuildVRT then GDALWarp like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324602/averaging-overlapping-rasters-with-gdal which talks about average but it should be easy to modify the process to create a sum.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you for your response and pointing toward that thread. It is exactly what I was looking for.