# GDAL VRT Pixel Function no output with signed or float data type

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, gdalbuildvrt

I am trying to average multiple partially overlapping rasters using a VRT and a Python based Pixel Function (https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#using-derived-bands-with-pixel-functions-in-python). The rasters have cells with no data.

The function on this page was my starting point: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324680/169329. The problem I am running into is that I am unable to change the `dataType` to one that allows me to have fractions and negative values without having useless output.

I have tried multiplying by 1000 and rounding the values before building the VRT and averaging the values using a Pixel Function, but this works only for positive values with `dataType UInt32`.

My expectation is that it should be possible to use other dataTypes in Pixel Functions besides those that only contain positive and rounded numbers. How can I do this?

I have used the following code after first multiplying the rasters by 1000 to try and get an average before dividing by 1000 again:

```xml
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Int32" band="1" subClass="VRTDerivedRasterBand">
<PixelFunctionType>average</PixelFunctionType>
<PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
<PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
    import numpy as np

    def average(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
        div = np.zeros(in_ar[0].shape, dtype = 'Int32')
        for i in range(len(in_ar)):
            div += (in_ar[i] != 0)

        div[div == 0] = 1
        y = np.sum(in_ar, axis = 0, dtype = 'Int32')
        y = y / div
        out_ar[:] = np.round(np.clip(y,-100000,100000))
]]>
</PixelFunctionCode>
```

Answer (score 4):

While I see this is an old post, I recently had the exact same issue and solved it like this:

```
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1" subClass="VRTDerivedRasterBand">
  <PixelFunctionType>average</PixelFunctionType>
  <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
  <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
    import numpy as np

    def average(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
        x = np.ma.masked_equal(in_ar, -3.4e+38)
        np.nanmean(x, axis = 0,out = out_ar, dtype = 'float64')
        mask = np.all(x.mask,axis = 0)
        out_ar[mask]=-3.4e+38
    ]]>
  </PixelFunctionCode>
```

The code first masks any NoData.  The no data value of -3.4e+38 is the default for a Float64 GDAL raster and this was my clue as to why it wasn't working - that and the overflow warning message.  Then, using `np.nanmean` allows me to do the calculation in a single step without first counting the number of overlaps.  I finally replace the masked values with my no data value.

However, I have to explicitly set dtype to 'float64' and when I used GDAL translate to 'fix' the result, I also had to explicitly define the input type also as Float64.  Any variation from these settings resulted in the overflow warning and nonsense in the output.