# Build VRT to merge overlapping rasters always takes max values?

Tags: qgis, resampling, gdalbuildvrt, mean

I'm attempting to merge two overlapping rasters from the same source with the same resolution. I would like the overlapping pixels to take the average value of the two overlapping pixels. When I select `Average` from Resampling Method, it takes the values from the higher raster values. Am I misunderstanding what this parameter is for?

sample pixel from merged VRT:

[image]

Same pixel from overlapping raster #1:

[image]

Same pixel from overlapping raster #2

[image]

So you can see that the result is the same as the layer with the higher value. For example, I want OUTPUT band 1 to be 445 (max) + 398 (min) / 2 = 422 (average).

I know Saga has a tool for this, but it requires splitting each band which is a bit involved. Would like to see if it can be done all at once first.

Comment: Simple VRT cannot mix overlapping images, it just selects the pixels from the last image. Those selected pixels can be resampled with a few methods (change pixel size from 1 m to 4 m -> average computes the average of 16 source pixels). However, with pixel functions in VRT you can do what you want, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324602/averaging-overlapping-rasters-with-gdal.